# Ubuntu 20.04: No Driver found for GeForce 6150Se nForce 430

Tags: 20.04, graphics

I've updated an old machine to Ubuntu 20.04. The default nouveau driver had a serious problem with the compositor. The screen fails all the time.

I've tried to run `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` that showed no result.

Is there a way to use this graphic card properly in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: There is no proprietary driver, nvidia-304, that fits that card, in Ubuntu 20.04 or 18.04, for that matter. An alternative driver, nouveau, should be in use. Not sure how many drivers you need and why.

Comment: @mikewhatever the nouveau driver doesn't work properly, indeed one cannot say it works, at all. The screen either fails or garbage.

Comment: Yeah, I know nouveau is not the best. Too bad Nvidia dropped support for nvidia-304 in 2017. Ubuntu 20.04 is way too much for that 16 year old GPU anyway - compositing, snaps, Gnome3, and what not. I'd try something lighter, say AntiX, and also think about a replacement.